# startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges not calling didUpdateLocations: when app is closed

Tags: ios, objective-c, location

Im building a simple ios app with IBeacon, Im using startMonitoringForRegion for detect beacons.

Thats working ok.

I also want to check the users location when the app is background or closed, for that purpose im using startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges. In background modes works ok, but when the app is closed the didUpdateLocations: callback is not fired.

My code (from AppDelegate.m) is below:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


    if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey])     {
        [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
        NSString *message = @"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey";
        [self sendLocalNotificationWithMessage:message];
    }

    UILocalNotification *localNotif =
    [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    if (localNotif)
    {

         NSString *idN = [localNotif.userInfo objectForKey:@"id_notif"];
        [self sendToDetail:idN];

    }

    if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        NSLog(@"RESPONDS!!!!!");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeSound|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge categories:nil]];
    }

    [self resetBadge];

       // Override point for customization after application launch.
        NSUUID *beaconUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6A"];
        NSString *regionIdentifier = @"iBeacons region 1";
        CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID: beaconUUID identifier: regionIdentifier ];
        beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];


        if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]){
         [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        }


     self.locationManager.delegate = self;
     //self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;

     [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];

     return YES;
    }

    - (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region{
      [manager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*) region];

     NSLog(@"didEnterRegion");

    }

    - (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region{
    [manager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*) region];

    NSLog(@"didExitRegion");

    }

    - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges");
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

    }

    - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
     NSLog(@"stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges");
    [self.locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

    }

    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

   NSString *message = @"didUpdateLocations";
        [self sendLocalNotificationWithMessage:message];

 CLLocation *currentLocation = locations[0];

        if (currentLocation != nil) {
            NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
            NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
            NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"longitud: %@ latitud: %@", longitude,latitude ];
             [self sendLocalNotificationWithMessage:message];

        }
    }
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: How long are you waiting for this callback?

Comment: I read that startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges delivers new events only when it detects changes to the device’s associated cell towers, resulting in less frequent updates and significantly lower power usage. So i checking it when im going to work, its about 5 km.

Comment: "It should not expect notifications more frequently than once every five minutes" - From the docs

Comment: Thanks but is not a time issue, i waited hours and no notification is send.

Comment: I added some code, im firing a notification in didUpdateLocations: callback. When the app is closed the notification in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: it is firing but the notification in didUpdateLocations: no.

Comment: Did you find a solution of how getting locations update when the app is killed ?

Comment: Its not a matter of time.  Its has to do with distance.  You have to travel far enough to switch cell towers to trigger startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges() .  I am having the same issue.

Comment: Got solution to get location update when app is killed ?